# Separation of clusters for ingestion and export

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Considering that a cluster is dominated by ingestion processes in terms of memory and cpu usage , is it better to have a separate follower cluster dedicated to only export? The use case is to export huge amount of data out of an ADX cluster by letting all the nodes participate in export. In other words, is there any disadvantage in using a follower cluster for export that the leader cluster itself? Or it will be a better strategy to simply scale up/out the main(leader) cluster itself for facilitating heavy export without having to do it through a follower cluster ? What is the best way to optimize export in this case? The export is to an external table which points to a storage in the same region as the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest scaling up/out the existing cluster, instead of creating a follower cluster. It will allow you easier management and you'll pay less.

To have efficient export, the recommendation is to export into parquet format, and use the `useNativeParquetWriter` flag, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-an-external-table).

Comment: got it, but let's say your ingestion cluster is pretty busy with executing a bunch of update policies , is it that accessing leader cluster data from a follower cluster going to be slow which is a concern here? I am just trying to understand drawbacks of accessing data from a follower cluster if any.  Does that cause delay ?

Comment: accessing the data from a follower incurs reading that data from blob storage of the leader onto the SSD caches of the follower.

Comment: so it appears that if for some reason the leader (ingestion) cluster is extremely busy (could be update policy execution etc. for example) , it might still be better to create exports from follower cluster , provided the data being pulled by export lies within the time window of hot cache policy of the follower , that way we can ensure that export is not really being forced to fetch data from the leader every time it exports , so let's say we have 5 min export window but the follower hot cache policy is 1 day, then export running on the follower will always end up pulling data from local SSD